# Texto no SOpt em inglês

Tags: debate, bug, tradução

Explanando o [pt.stackoverflow.com](https://pt.stackoverflow.com) me deparei com a seguinte situação:

Acontece que quando não há perguntas com recompensas oferecidas, o site mostra o seguinte texto em inglês:

> No questions found. Perhaps you'd like to select a different tab?

Imagem abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como proceder para contribuir com o nosso SO nessa situação?

Comment: Vai no link [SOpt Translations ](https://pt.traducir.win/) .

Comment: @AugustoVasques e André, o Matheus já enviou a algum tempo https://pt.traducir.win/string/9308, marquei como urgente, porque é um texto que aparece muito. Agora é esperar os revisores para então um mod enviar ao transifex, o processo demora um pouco, mas em breve estará ok :)